# Faster way to call a method in c++

Tags: c++

Quick question and I apologize if it sounds naive.
What is faster in c++. A code like this:

```
ProgramsManager::CurrentProgram->Uniforms->Set(n1);
ProgramsManager::CurrentProgram->Uniforms->Set(n2);
ProgramsManager::CurrentProgram->Uniforms->Set(n3);
ProgramsManager::CurrentProgram->Uniforms->Set(...);
```

Or this one?

```
Uniforms* u = ProgramsManager::CurrentProgram->Uniforms;
u->Set(n1);
u->Set(n2);
u->Set(n3);
u->Set(...);
```

I know the second piece of code is faster in interpreted languages, but I feel like it makes no difference in compiled languages. Am I right?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You are right. Any decent compiler will produce identical object code for both.

Comment: @Dúthomhas The compiler will only create the same code for both, if it can be sure that `Set` would not change `ProgramsManager::CurrentProgram` or `Uniforms`

Comment: Bottom line is profile it and see. I have known such explicit caching to provide benefits. Its not always easy to know what the compiler will or won't optimize away.

Comment: The truth is in the assembly language.  Optimization settings will affect the assembly language instructions emitted.  Print the assembly language for both and compare.  Also try with different optimization settings.

Comment: @Galik While I haven't found caching a function pointer to be useful, I have found caching an int value (so something like int i = val->x->pos;) to provide measurable benefits.

Comment: Speed is not defined by the C++ programming language. **Measure it.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second might be faster, but it won't be faster by a lot.

The reason it might be faster is if the compiler cannot prove to itself that `ProgramsManager::CurrentProgram->Uniforms` could be changed by the calls to `...->Set`. If it can't prove this, it will have to re-evaluate the expression `ProgramsManager::CurrentProgram->Uniforms` for each line.

However, modern CPUs are usually fairly quick at this kind of thing, and compilers are getting better.

Comment: Depends on how many variables are passed, and how many registers are available for passing the variables.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 choices here, not 2.

1. Call a single parameter function.
2. Call one function with many parameters.
3. Call a single function with container, like `struct` or `vector`.

### Fundamental Overhead

When calling a function there is an overhead of instructions.  Usually this involves placing values in registers or on the stack or something else.

Lower level, there may be the possibility of the processor having to reload it's instruction cache / pipe line.

### Optimizing The Function Call

For optimizing function calls, the best method is to avoid the call by pasting the code (a.k.a. inlining).  This removes the overhead.

The next best is to reduce the number of function calls.  For example, passing more parameters will use less function calls and less overhead.

### Many Parameters versus One Container

The optimal function call passes values by registers.  Extra parameters, more than the available registers, results in using the *stack memory*.  This means that the function will need code to retrieve the values from the *stack memory*.

Passing many parameters using the stack incurs an overhead.  Also, the function signature will need to change if more parameters are added or removed.

Placing variables into a container reduces the overhead.  Only a pointer (or reference) to the container needs to be passed.  This usually involves only a register since pointers usually fit into a register (many compilers pass structures by reference using pointers).

Another benefit to the container is that the container can change without having to change the function signature.